# How to align Floating Action Button to center

Tags: android, android-xml, floating-action-button

I have one FloatingActionButton. I want it to be middle of 2 LinearLayouts and center of screen like this.  [image]

Currently My design is like this

[image]

I want it to be at the exact center of the screen. How to do that?

This is my whole xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Comment: Can you post your whole xml layout?

Comment: I have edited the question. My whole xml code is there

Comment: Does `app:layout_anchorGravity="center"` work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your **`CoordinatorLayout`** is a `FrameLayout` , So try this way, 
  I hope it will helps you .

```
 app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
```

Comment: This should work because CoordinatorLayout is a FrameLayout, not a RelativeLayout where `layout_centerHorizontal="true"` would work.

Answer (score 5):

Above solutions did not work for me somehow. 
I changed the `android:layout_gravity` to

`android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"`

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Setting layout_centerHorizontal and layout_centerInParent won't work in a CoordinatorLayout. They are only allowed in a RelativeLayout. You should do it like this:

```
app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```